# AWK Command to Select Date Range

Tags: awk, logs, date

I would like to monitor the /var/log/secure file for user activity.
I need to be able to provide a start date and select lines only occurring after that date . I have played around with awk for a while and have not been able to find a solution that works. I have had some commands that appear to work but just end up selecting every line from the file. In the command below I am trying to select all entries after July 9th, 2019.

```
cat /var/log/secure* | awk '{d=system("date -d "$1 $2, 2019 $3" +%s"); if ( 1562731201 < d );  print}'
awk: cmd. line:1: {d=system("date -d "$1 $2, 2019 $3" +%s"); if ( 1562731201 > d );  print}
awk: cmd. line:1:                                         ^ 2 is invalid as number of arguments for system

date -d @1562644801
Tue Jul  9 00:00:01 EDT 2019
```

Any help you can provide would be appreciated.

Comment: If you use GNU awk, then use its [builtin `mktime()` function](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Time-Functions) instead of calling out to `date` for every line. Should be a lot faster, but you make have to do a little more work to build the string argument for mktime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe Below command may work, As tested it worked fine for me

```
sed -n '/Jul 9 [0-9]\{2\}:/,$p' /var/log/secure| sed '/Jul 9 [0-9]\{2\}:/d'
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay in my response Praveen,  I appreciate your answer.
If you are willing and have time can you please explain what this command is actually doing?

Comment: It will select all lines after July 9 2019 till last line tested and worked too

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the inner quotation marks.

```
"date -d \"$1 $2, 2019 $3\" +%s"
```

So turn it into

```
'{d=system("date -d \"$1 $2, 2019 $3\" +%s"); if ( 1562731201 < d );  print}'
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Panki. looks like the date command is not accepting the parameters passed to it and it is printing entries before July 9.                    
date: invalid date ‘ , 2019 ’
Jul  8 01:44:32 server1 sshd[34408]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)

Comment: Assuming $1,$2,$3 are awk fields, they can't be inside a quoted string: `cmd=sprintf("date -d \"%s %s, 2019 %s\" +%%s", $1, $2, $3), d = system(cmd)`

Comment: @glennjackman Post this as an answer if it ends up working for OP

Comment: Feel free to put it in your answer.

Comment: `cat /var/log/secure* | awk '{cmd=sprintf("date -d \"%s %s, 2019 %s\" +%%s", $1, $2, $3), d = system(cmd); if ( 1562731201 < d );  print}'` gives a syntax error on this comma before the d "......$3), d = system(cmd)....." if I change it to a semicolon it selects entries before July 9th.

Comment: Wait, does that mean that if you change the comparison to `>` it works? I don't understand...

Comment: @Panki no it just selects every line in the file